# Changing the application Context from root to myApp

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat7

I am working on a java wen application which was deployed at root in `Tomcat's /webapp/ROOT` directory. while running tomcat from Eclipse `tomcat` provided a context path as `/myApp` but when I click on any link or button which creates another request context path is not added to the link. Please share your thoughts how can I add new context path to every request at once.

Comment: Each URL request shall start with your root context only. Though you can change this in your web.xml

Comment: Thanks @SacJn can you tell me ho can I do it with web.xml

Comment: Please check your web.xml or findout the importance of this file. You will findout the structure of this file has this tag for context. It has many more features so I would suggest you to exploring this file

Comment: @SacJn I know the importance please read the question carefully I am asking about the way to add conext name at once

Comment: Do you mean I missed **"new context path to every request at once"**.